# Is aborting a POST XHR reliable?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Running an apache server with PHP 5.4.

I have a form that posts an xhr request to the server and aborts previous requests if the button is pushed again before the current xhr is finished.

So if I sit there, clicking the button as fast as possible (within about 100-150ms) and seeing all the cancelled XHR's piling up in my network tab and then let the **last** request actually finish, I check the server and see that all of the cancelled requests actually "completed" their task on the server (connects to a database and drops some data in a table).

Also may be relevant: The only thing that happens after the "work" (the insertion into the database) is the sending of a status string back to the client.

I read that you shouldn't rely on cancelling HTTP requests to actual cancel the server process, but something smells fishy here.

Is it reliable to cancel XHR requests or is something going on with my server?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

Comment: The XMLHttpRequest abort method is ok but if the request has already been sent to the server then the server will process the request even if we abort the request. The client will not wait for/handle the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XMLHttpRequest abort is only used to prevent holding up the UI, but it does not cancel the server request.

So the answer? It's unreliable for the server.

If you plan on preventing multiple requests at once, you can use either 1) server side queuing or 2) a simple disable of the action button while the request is in process (renabling the button only when the request finishes). I would say the latter is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is a stateless protocol. When you abort your `POST` from the client, it just keeps the client from listening for a response, but the `POST` has already been sent off to the server. When the server receives the request, it doesn't sit around, waiting for another request; it simply performs the action associated with a `POST` request to the given resource.